# How to create button in context menu on component/page right click

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How to create button in context menu on component/page right click.

I tried to configure my extension.config file by refering as mentioned in "http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/10/helloworld-extension-for-tridion-2011/" but i was unable to see any button available.

Could anyone suggest me.

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser cache and/or restart IIS, else you will want to start with double checking every step in that example

Comment: Even better: increase the `Update` number in your System.xml as suggested here: http://www.curlette.com/?p=854&cpage=1#comment-1155.

Comment: Yes i tried to clear the browser cache. When i follow the steps mentioned mentioned in " http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/10/helloworld-extension-for-tridion-2011/ " like creating a virtual directory for the physical path of the source file(unzipped file) 2. Configuring it in Configuration-->System.config.

Comment: When i try to refresh tridion i ma facing the following error "Loading configuration file "F:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\customizations\HelloWorld\config\HelloWorld.config" failed: The element 'extensions' in namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge' has invalid child element 'taskbars' in namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions'. List of possible elements expected: 'resourceextensions, editorextensions, modelextensions, dataextenders' in namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your configuration file (F:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\customizations\HelloWorld\config\HelloWorld.config) for unclosed tags or some typo.

To create button in context menu:

1. Check that your HelloWorld.config extends contextmenu node

   ```xml
   <ext:contextmenus>
       <ext:add>
           <ext:extension name="Hello World" assignid="" insertbefore="cm_preview">
               <ext:menudeclaration>
                   <cmenu:ContextMenuItem id="HelloWorld" name="Hello World" command="HelloWorld"/>
               </ext:menudeclaration>
               <ext:dependencies>
                   <cfg:dependency>RandomStringThatNeedsToBeCompiled2</cfg:dependency>
               </ext:dependencies>
               <ext:apply>
                   <ext:view name="DashboardView"/>
               </ext:apply>
           </ext:extension>
       </ext:add>
   </ext:contextmenus>
   ```
2. Modify your helloworld.js to enable button only for Components

   ```js
   Common.Tridion.MVP.HelloWorld.prototype.isAvailable = function HelloWorld$isAvailable(selection)
   {
       var itemID = selection.getItem(0);
       if ($models.getItemType(itemID) != $const.ItemType.COMPONENT) {
           return false;
       }
   };
   ```

Don't forget to clear your cache